# How to pass value from Google Map to other activity?

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

I want to pass value from a Google Map to other activity. Until now I fetched the values using JSON parser and inserted on Google Map. But now I want to pass "ID" to other activity when user click on "Infowindow". How can I achieve this?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    String titlee, snipett, ii,a;
    Double latitude, longitude;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //*** Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
        String url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/krishi.php";
        try {

            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(request(url));

            location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("LocationID", c.getString("id"));
                map.put("Latitude", c.getString("latitude"));
                map.put("Longitude", c.getString("longitude"));
                map.put("Type", c.getString("listed_name"));
                map.put("Title", c.getString("title"));
                location.add(map);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GoogleMap googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();

        latitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(0).get("Latitude"));
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(0).get("Longitude"));
        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 12));

        for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {
            latitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("Latitude"));
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("Longitude"));
            final String name = location.get(i).get("Title");
            String sel = location.get(i).get("Type");
            a = location.get(i).get("LocationID");

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
           markerOptions.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(name).snippet(sel);
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            marker.showInfoWindow();

        }

        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {



            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }


            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);


                titlee = arg0.getTitle();
                snipett = arg0.getSnippet();
                TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
                tvLat.setText("Area Name: " + titlee);
                tvLng.setText("Type: " + snipett);

                return v;

            }

        });


        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {





            }
        });



    }

    private String request(String urlString) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StringBuilder chaine = new StringBuilder("");
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                chaine.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return chaine.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please note that [urgent designations](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) are usually not received well here - if you can make a mental note to omit these kinds of messages, volunteers here will appreciate it `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Id and pass to the new Activity through

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
i.putExtra("Id", intId);
startActivity(i);
```

Retrieve it in SecondScreen like:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    Int id = extras.getInt("Id"); // retrieve the data using keyName
```

Comment: How do i get "ID" when user click on infobutton?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way:

Initialize variables:

```
 private GoogleMap mMap;
 private HashMap<Marker, Integer> mHashMap = new HashMap<Marker,Integer>();
 private ArrayList<MyCustomModelClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyCustomModelClass>();
```

Add marker on google map using your arraylist:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
 double latitude = myList.getLatitude();
 double longitude = myList.getLongitude();
 Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))).title(myList.getTitle())
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon));
 mHashMap.put(marker, i);

}
```

On marker click listener:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) { 
   int pos = mHashMap.get(marker);
   Log.i("Position of arraylist", pos+"");
}
```